# Why do phase changes occur?

Tags: phase

**So** I was doing a Gizmo for my Science class and I came across this question: "Why do phase changes occur?" I could not find anything about it in my resources. Does anybody here know the answer?

Answer (score 2):

They occur because that's just how physics works. There isn't anything profound going on. Let's take water as an example. Water boils because enough energy has been introduced into the system such that molecules are able to break away from the interactions keeping them in the liquid state.